# Problem with Monitor, flickering green

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I have the MacBookPro 15'' mid 2009 (10.9.3) , and from today I have green flickering on my monitor.

I did try with Reset PRAM, Repair Disk, also TechToolPro but i have the same problem.

It seem that the problem is with "black Color"

[image: Example Image]
[image: Second Example Image]

If I change the "total Black" I can "fix" the problem...

If i connect my Macbook with second Monitor, in Second monitor I haven't the problem but in "main monitor" the problem remains

What can I try ?

Comment: Run Apple hardware test. What external app are you using for Graphics driver.

Comment: Start in Safe mode to see if it is still there.

Comment: @Buscar웃 In Safe Mode the problem remains. What do you mean with external app?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear it is the hardware (your screen) but the Safe mode indicates that.

things you can try

- Disable Automatic Graphics Switching
- run Apple Hardware test.. Press D during startup
- disable any graphics controllers (external software) like the TechToolPro
- Reset PRAM/NVRAM..press Option-Command-P-R until you hear startup sound a second time.
- reinstall OS
- NONE of the above worked..lets get to the final step..Hardware.. it might be the Cable..see [instructions here how to get to it](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2009+LCD+Replacement/3574), just pull it out and back in, while you are at it vacuum clean the interior.

<sub>This is considered a Very difficult surgery, so if you are not of a steady hand and very handy with tools, skip the step and go to professional place.</sub>

Comment: I try to Reset PRAM/NVRAM, but nothing to new.
I try also Press D during startup (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) but not enter in Diagnostics. My Mac is Mid 2009 with Mavericks

Comment: Loose cable can be quite good at causing color flicker. Apple didn't spare any effort to make it easy to get to either. If it *is* the cable, shaking the Macbook while watching the screen, or hitting it in just the right place (see link) might verify the problem before you go to a **lot** of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

After my MacBook Pro (15 inch, late 2008, 10.9.5) fell down this morning, I had a similar problem - just that in my case, the flickering was in red pixels, everywhere where a black color was displayed.

I rebooted, and on bootup, screen was completely black. I got a small screwdriver, and opened the back (removed battery, unplugged power cable...), then (very) carefully pushed and wiggled the display connector, which I found following the pictures in the link in Buscar's post. After reboot, screen was there again, however, the red pixel problem was still present.

I opened again the back, this time also vacuum cleaned the dust out of it, and again touched the display cable connector. And miracle happened, upon reboot, the red pixel problem had disappeared.

Comment: I'm very Happy for you. At the beginning the screen returned in "normal" state, but after a lot of time the problem has changed permanently

Comment: I had the same problem with my MacBook Pro (15 inch, mid 2010) after slightly hitting the computer into a door. After that, the black pixels on the screen flickered in bright green. The solution for me was to open up the case with a PH00 screwdriver, blow it with a sprayduster, and very carefully wiggle on the display connector (the cord next to the outermost fan in the bottom left corner when the computer is turn upside down).